# I want to make a custom animation when I use List Shuffle

Tags: flutter, animation

I'm a beginner at Flutter and it's almost my first time using an animation.
I uploaded the posts and listed the uploaded posts as a `GridView.builder`.

And there is a function to `shuffle()` this list to change the order of the list.
When I `shuffle()` the list, I want to make an animation like as below image.

Can I get some advice on what to do to do this?

[image]

Comment: use `list.shuffle()` method

Comment: based on animation, you can use Stack with AnimatedPosition